# Does Apportable support GLKit? Android shows blank screen for lightly modified GL ES2.0 sample app

Tags: android, apportable

What I did was create a fresh "OpenGL ES Game" project in XCode, and then tweaked it a bit.

I am receiving this from `apportable log` when I run the app on the device:

```
V/AudioPlayer( 5819): Verde AudioPlayer init: 256
I/ActivityManager(  509): Displayed slu.modelviewer/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity: +667ms
V/ApportableOrientationEventListener( 5819): deviceModel = Nexus 7, orientation adjustment = false
I/NSLog   ( 5819): Options are: (nil)
W/ActivityManager(  509): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=slu.modelviewer/com.apportable.notifications.LocalNotificationService } U=0: not found
D/Finsky  ( 3102): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
```

This `Unable to start service Intent { ... }` bit looks to be the part where things go bad. I am trying to google `com.apportable.notifications.LocalNotificationService` and not finding many leads. The only things I've been able to find are two pastebin dumps (and this here SO post).

The app shows a blank black screen.

I do know that this occurs after the NSLog event (`Options are: (nil)`) which is written in `AppDelegate.m` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSLog(@"Options are: %@", launchOptions.description);
    return YES;
}
```

Hopefully it is some simple configuration to get right. I hope someone can point me to where the configuration and documentation lives for this.

*More info:*

My device is a 2013 Nexus 7.

Here is some more diagnostic output:

```
$ apportable just_debug
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Loading configuration.
Finished parsing configuration.
scons: Building targets ...
Debugging...
Starting: Intent { cmp=slu.modelviewer/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }

Attaching to pid 6751
Starting service: Intent { act=slu.modelviewer.GdbServerService (has extras) }
1574 KB/s (9560 bytes in 0.005s)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-android-github.com/darchons-apportable Jun 27 2013 14:33:35
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 --target=arm-elf-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 6 libraries, e.g. libEGL_adreno200.so.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0x40082b79 to 0x40082b78.
0x400c2408 in epoll_wait ()
   from /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libc.so
$1 = 0
$2 = 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x74041c58: file /Users/lust/Documents/modelviewer/modelviewer/main.m, line 14.
[New Thread 6769]
[Switching to Thread 6769]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=0, argv=0x73ef8860 <_start_method>)
    at /Users/lust/Documents/modelviewer/modelviewer/main.m:14
14  {
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x4007fa30  0x4008a510  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/linker
0x400b29b8  0x400e1900  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libc.so
0x400fe828  0x400fe9c8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstdc++.so
0x401038f0  0x40116338  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libm.so
0x400a1f50  0x400a3490  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/liblog.so
0x40096958  0x4009c9bc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcutils.so
0x4013bb1c  0x4013e20c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libgccdemangle.so
0x401371a0  0x40138458  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcorkscrew.so
0x40143c00  0x40153724  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libz.so
0x40127d68  0x401308e4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libutils.so
0x40171a34  0x4017a6a0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libbinder.so
0x404921c4  0x40492624  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libemoji.so
0x40498270  0x404c6834  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libjpeg.so
0x404ce774  0x404dd3a0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libexpat.so
0x4059e3a8  0x405b4684  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstlport.so
0x40558860  0x405800f0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libGLES_trace.so
0x404eda6c  0x405174dc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libEGL.so
0x405bffb4  0x405c2328  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libGLESv2.so
0x402cc7f0  0x4044906c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libskia.so
0x40248558  0x4025b360  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libandroidfw.so
0x405c57a0  0x405c5ef0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libnativehelper.so
0x405ca53c  0x405ccc08  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libnetutils.so
0x405dc5f0  0x405dc830  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libhardware.so
0x405df58c  0x405df730  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libsync.so
0x405d56bc  0x405d85bc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libui.so
0x405fe3d8  0x4060a78c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libgui.so
0x4064436c  0x4064607c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcamera_metadata.so
0x4063109c  0x406380f8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcamera_client.so
0x4079db84  0x4079dfcc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libgabi++.so
0x406cb220  0x40751e3c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libicuuc.so
0x407ee068  0x408b42d0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libicui18n.so
0x4064f9d0  0x4068f7e4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libsqlite.so
0x40982b60  0x40988474  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libselinux.so
0x408ecb80  0x40958550  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libdvm.so
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x4098f180  0x40990d10  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libGLESv1_CM.so
0x4099350c  0x409940a4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libETC1.so
0x4099e120  0x4099ea20  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libwpa_client.so
0x409988e0  0x4099a4e4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libhardware_legacy.so
0x409a4798  0x409b5530  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libsonivox.so
0x40a287a0  0x40a933e4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcrypto.so
0x40adcb18  0x40afb098  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libssl.so
0x40b95ef8  0x40b99160  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_foundation.so
0x40ba19a8  0x40ba46c4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libspeexresampler.so
0x40b9db20  0x40b9e6f8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libaudioutils.so
0x40b4c538  0x40b6a960  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libmedia.so
0x40ba7ed0  0x40ba88a4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libusbhost.so
0x40baebf0  0x40be51b4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libharfbuzz_ng.so
0x40e7de18  0x41401c88  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libLLVM.so
0x40d52828  0x40d6b204  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libbcinfo.so
0x40cd6f60  0x40d18ebc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libbcc.so
0x40c473b8  0x40c8a008  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libRS.so
0x41531ce8  0x41534664  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libRScpp.so
0x40c024f8  0x40c1f080  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libhwui.so
0x401c4118  0x4020a860  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libandroid_runtime.so
0x6fc2fe80  0x6fc50db8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libjavacore.so
0x71c80990  0x71c86018  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libdrmframework.so
0x71c6da10  0x71c6f48c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libdrmframework_jni.so
0x71e05884  0x71e0b028  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_omx.so
0x71c96d00  0x71c975e0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_yuv.so
0x71e13c50  0x71e1ea90  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvorbisidec.so
0x71c9a514  0x71c9a618  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_enc_common.so
0x71c9e0a0  0x71ca0ef4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_avc_common.so
0x71d4b910  0x71dbe9c8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright.so
0x71e33f14  0x71e392c0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libmtp.so
0x71e419e8  0x71e45cf0  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libexif.so
0x71e4d5c4  0x71e502f8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
0x71ce0a0c  0x71cf5acc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libmedia_jni.so
0x71ca4b58  0x71ca5818  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libexif_jni.so
0x71e5ac10  0x71e5b180  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
c8/libs/libsoundpool.so
0x71ed0198  0x71ed2870  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libcommon_time_client.so
0x71edb3d0  0x71edcea4  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libnbaio.so
0x71ee0a38  0x71ee1414  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libeffects.so
0x71ee59f0  0x71ee5e1c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libpowermanager.so
0x71e9fbc8  0x71eb960c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libaudioflinger.so
0x71f22ce4  0x71f2485c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvideoeditor_osal.so
0x71f2766c  0x71f29018  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvideoeditor_videofilters.so
0x71f37ae8  0x71f42894  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvideoeditorplayer.so
0x71ef4ec0  0x71f17f40  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvideoeditor_core.so
0x71e65488  0x71e6bc94  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libvideoeditor_jni.so
0x71f4e138  0x71f50034  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/librs_jni.so
0x71f7dd48  0x71f807c8  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libandroid.so
0x72880e90  0x7296edfc  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libchromium_net.so
0x71f89e28  0x71fafb54  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libharfbuzz.so
0x72244df0  0x72649700  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libwebcore.so
0x7322903c  0x73278360  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libv.so
0x73545b84  0x735b810c  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libcxx.so
0x733d2108  0x733e0fe4  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libSystem.so
0x735e91e0  0x7360afa0  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libobjc.so
0x733e8f6c  0x733f27d8  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libffi.so
0x73617110  0x736201a0  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libpthread_workqueue.so
0x73628ba0  0x7363e3c0  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libdispatch.so
0x736ecdc8  0x739a02b8  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
0x73b3ece8  0x73b947ac  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libOpenAL.so
0x720fe510  0x720fe68c  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libjnigraphics.so
0x73bc2bc0  0x73c149c0  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libBridgeKit.so
0x73d2b174  0x74049cf4  Yes         /Users/lust/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/modelviewer/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
0x741b3b88  0x741bb874  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libgsl.so
                        No          libEGL_adreno200.so
                        No          libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
                        No          libGLESv2_adreno200.so
                        No          eglsubAndroid.so
                        No          libq3dtools_adreno200.so
0x743a8af8  0x746b13e6  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libsc-a3xx.so
0x74b07aa0  0x74b08488  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libqdutils.so
0x74b02178  0x74b02d64  Yes (*)     /Users/lust/.apportable/cache/devices/059ef6c8/libs/libmemalloc.so
                        No          gralloc.msm8960.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb)
(gdb)
```

In particular I am worried about it listing `No` for `libGLESv2_adreno200.so` and `libEGL_adreno200.so`...

Corresponding output from the log:

```
I/ActivityManager(  509): Start proc slu.modelviewer for activity slu.modelviewer/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity: pid=6751 uid=10078 gids={50078, 3003, 1028}
D/APPLICATION( 6751): Running application callbacks
D/CrashReporter( 6751): New install
D/CrashReporter( 6751): Existing install
D/CrashReporter( 6751): Existing install
V/ApportableOrientationEventListener( 6751): deviceModel = Nexus 7, orientation adjustment = false
D/dalvikvm( 6751): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 168K, 3% free 8923K/9116K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 6751): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.079MB for 2457616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 6751): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 11322K/11520K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm( 6751): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 11322K/11520K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 13ms
D/dalvikvm( 6751): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 2% free 11323K/11520K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 6751): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.166MB for 8478736-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 6751): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 19603K/19804K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm( 6751): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
D/dalvikvm( 6751): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
V/com.apportable.AssetManager( 6751): App Expansion Files: main: version:0 size:0.
V/com.apportable.AssetManager( 6751): App does not have Expansion Files
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Scanning ABI armeabi
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Scanning ABI armeabi-v7a
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Won't patch libraries - '/storage/emulated/0/libs/slu.modelviewer' doesn't exist
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'v'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libv.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libv.so 0x41e0ddb8
W/ContextImpl( 6751): Unable to create external cache directory
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 5 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'cxx'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libcxx.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libcxx.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libcxx.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 2 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'System'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libSystem.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libSystem.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libSystem.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 0 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'objc'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libobjc.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libobjc.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libobjc.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 1 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'ffi'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libffi.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libffi.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libffi.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 0 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'pthread_workqueue'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libpthread_workqueue.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libpthread_workqueue.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libpthread_workqueue.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 2 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'dispatch'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libdispatch.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libdispatch.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libdispatch.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 1 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'Foundation'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libFoundation.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libFoundation.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libFoundation.so 0x41e0ddb8, skipping init
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 20 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'OpenAL'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libOpenAL.so 0x41e0ddb8
I/OpenAL_SLES( 6751): alc_opensles_init
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libOpenAL.so 0x41e0ddb8
I/OpenAL_SLES( 6751): API:18
I/OpenAL_SLES( 6751): Model:Nexus 7
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 3 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'BridgeKit'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libBridgeKit.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libBridgeKit.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 11 ms
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loading library 'verde'...
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libverde.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/dalvikvm( 6751): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/slu.modelviewer-2/libverde.so 0x41e0ddb8
D/LibraryManager( 6751): Loaded in 34 ms
D/dalvikvm(  509): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2051K, 22% free 34096K/43244K, paused 3ms+9ms, total 96ms
D/libEGL  ( 6751): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
D/libEGL  ( 6751): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
D/libEGL  ( 6751): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/Adreno200-EGL( 6751): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6751): Enabling debug mode 0
D/VerdeActivity( 6751): No updater.
V/choosePreferredConfigOrder( 6751): using fast_color
V/Apportable( 6751): About to try 27 configurations
V/Apportable( 6751): Chosen EGLConfig accepted:
V/Apportable( 6751): conf = com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLConfigImpl@42b08528
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_RED_SIZE = 5
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_GREEN_SIZE = 6
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_BLUE_SIZE = 5
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_ALPHA_SIZE = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_DEPTH_SIZE = 24
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_STENCIL_SIZE = 8
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_BUFFER_SIZE = 16
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_CONFIG_ID = 3
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_LEVEL = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH = 4096
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT = 4096
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_PIXELS = 16777216
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID = 4
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_TYPE = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_SAMPLES = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE = 12344
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_CONFIG_CAVEAT = 12344 (12344,12368,12369)
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE = 0
V/Apportable( 6751): EGL_SURFACE_TYPE = 1445 EGL_WINDOW_BIT=4 EGL_PBUFFER_BIT=1 EGL_PIXMAP_BIT=2
V/AudioPlayer( 6751): Verde AudioPlayer init: 256
I/ActivityManager(  509): Displayed slu.modelviewer/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity: +677ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 6797):
D/AndroidRuntime( 6797): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 6797): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm( 6797): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 6797): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 6797): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 6797): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/AndroidRuntime( 6797): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime( 6797): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm( 6797): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 18% free 479K/580K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 2ms
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml that I find in the target folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="slu.modelviewer"
          android:sharedUserId="slu.modelviewer"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          android:versionCode="1376873516"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:name="com.apportable.app.VerdeApplication"
                 android:hasCode="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@style/FullScreenActivity"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:largeHeap="false"
                 android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs" android:value="v cxx System objc ffi pthread_workqueue dispatch Foundation OpenAL BridgeKit verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="verde" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app_name" android:value="modelviewer" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.splash_screen_type" android:value="letterbox" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.orientation" android:value="landscape" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles2" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles.fast_color" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="apportable.abi_list" android:value="" />
        <activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"
                  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.apportable.activity.GdbServerService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="slu.modelviewer.GdbServerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: The `No` for `libGLESv2_adreno200.so` and `libEGL_adreno200.so` only refer to whether debugging symbols are available or not. It is nothing to be concerned about, perfectly normal, and undoubtedly not the cause of your problems. I don't know much about apportable, but do you have an AndroidManifest.xml you could put into your answer? It might help to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Currently that is the major culprit of UI not displaying. As of current Apportable not have support for storyboards (however XIB interfaces are supported)

Comment: Turns out storyboard wasn't being used.

Comment: So I got some stuff to render in GL ES 2; everything is still more or less mysterious, but at least it looks like the LocalNotificationService was a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Maybe you need just change opaque for your view.
[Here](https://github.com/apportable/glkit_bunny) my example forked by apportable.

Comment: Support is not complete, AFAICS, GLMatrix utility functions, for example, are not available.